# Android: How to send push notification to other users with the same app?

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Recently, I'm trying to make a app that will send a simple notification to the user with a certain ID with the same app. However, since I'm new to these types of development, I want to know if I should use a GCM or if there are some better options. I've searched over google but couldn't get a good solution to it. If possible I would want some tips.

Comment: GCM is good. Othere third parties are available. It depends on your/ client's  requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi in my oppinion and from personal experience, i belive that in case when you are not sure, or dont know for better solution, it is best to use what Google offers you,in this case GCM, which works quite nice.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html here you can get all infos what you need about GCM.

Comment: Thanks!  I know that at first it might be challenging but I'll try.